# ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable (TFCamemBERT)

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, huggingface-transformers, named-entity-recognition

Currently I am working on Named Entity Recognition in the medical domain using Camembert, precisely using the model: [TFCamembert](https://huggingface.co/jplu/tf-camembert-base).

However I have some problems with the fine-tuning of the model for my task as I am using a private dataset not available on Hugging Face.

The data is divided into text files and annotation files. The text file contains for example:

```
Le cas présenté concerne un homme âgé de 61 ans (71 kg, 172 cm, soit un indice de masse corporelle de 23,9 kg/m²) admissible à une transplantation pulmonaire en raison d’une insuffisance respiratoire chronique terminale sur emphysème post-tabagique, sous oxygénothérapie continue (1 L/min) et ventilation non invasive nocturne. Il présente, comme principaux antécédents, une dyslipidémie, une hypertension artérielle et un tabagisme sevré estimé à 21 paquets-années (facteurs de risque cardiovasculaires). Le bilan préopératoire a révélé une hypertension artérielle pulmonaire essentiellement postcapillaire conduisant à l’ajout du périndopril (2 mg par jour) et du furosémide (40 mg par jour). La mise en évidence d’un Elispot (enzyme-linked immunospot) positif pour la tuberculose a motivé l’introduction d’un traitement prophylactique par l’association rifampicine-isoniazide (600-300 mg par jour) pour une durée de trois mois.
Deux mois après le bilan préopératoire, le patient a bénéficié d’une transplantation mono-pulmonaire gauche sans dysfonction primaire du greffon5,6. Le donneur et le receveur présentaient tous deux un statut sérologique positif pour cytomegalovirus (CMV) et Epstein Barr Virus (EBV). Une sérologie positive de la toxoplasmose a été mise en évidence uniquement chez le receveur. Le traitement immunosuppresseur d’induction associait la méthylprednisolone (500 mg à jour 0 et 375 mg à jour +1 post-transplantation) et le basiliximab, anticorps monoclonal dirigé contre l’interleukine-2 (20 mg à jour 0 et jour +4 posttransplantation). À partir de jour +2 post-transplantation, l’immunosuppression a été maintenue par une trithérapie par voie orale comprenant le tacrolimus à une posologie initiale de 5 mg par jour, le mofétil mycophénolate (MMF) 2000 mg par jour et la prednisone 20 mg par jour. Les traitements associés sont présentés dans le tableau I.
L’évolution est marquée par la survenue, au jour +5 posttransplantation, d’une dégradation respiratoire sur œdème pulmonaire gauche de reperfusion, avec possible participation cardiogénique. Le rejet aigu de grade III, évoqué par la présence d’infiltrats lymphocytaires aux biopsies transbronchiques, a été confirmé par l’anatomopathologie.
```

While the annotation file looks like:

```
T1 genre 28 33 homme
T2 age 41 47 61 ans
A1 genre T1 masculin
T3 origine 127 326 une transplantation pulmonaire en raison d’une insuffisance respiratoire chronique terminale sur emphysème post-tabagique, sous oxygénothérapie continue (1 L/min) et ventilation non invasive nocturne
T4 issue 1962 2104 une dégradation respiratoire sur œdème pulmonaire gauche de reperfusion, avec possible participation cardiogénique. Le rejet aigu de grade III
A2 issue T4 détérioration
```

More details about the prepossessing of [the data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Odq6eTexLg9ZXCjbWbnZiWMGAqg9Ut45/view?usp=sharing) can be found in this [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1oqCRFFvzSjDBpfCk5nS2KjBvzCr34Rqz?usp=sharing).

The things is that the internal loss of my model does not work, if I run the training of the model without declaring a loss, it does not work, I have to define a loss to be able to run the training!

Here is my train_data converted to Tensor slice dataset.

```
train_label_encodings = tf.convert_to_tensor(train_label_encodings, dtype=tf.int32)
train_label_encodings.data

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((
    dict(train_text_encodings.data),
    train_label_encodings.data
))
train_dataset
```

```
<TensorSliceDataset shapes: ({input_ids: (512,), offset_mapping: (512, 2)}, (512,)), types: ({input_ids: tf.int32, offset_mapping: tf.int32}, tf.int32)>
```

I define the model:

```
# Import the model and define an optimizer
from transformers import TFAutoModelForTokenClassification, TFCamembertModel, create_optimizer
import tensorflow as tf

num_train_steps = len(train_dataset) * 5
optimizer, lr_schedule = create_optimizer(
    init_lr = 5e-6,
    num_train_steps = num_train_steps,
    weight_decay_rate = 0.01,
    num_warmup_steps = 0
)

metric = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy('accuracy')

model = TFAutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained(model_id, num_labels=len(unique_labels), label2id=label2id, id2label=id2label)

model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Here is the summary of the model:

```
Model: "tf_camembert_for_token_classification_2"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 roberta (TFRobertaMainLayer  multiple                 110031360 
 )                                                               
                                                                 
 dropout_113 (Dropout)       multiple                  0         
                                                                 
 classifier (Dense)          multiple                  25377     
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 110,056,737
Trainable params: 110,056,737
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

When I try to launch the training, I get the following error:

```
import os
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard

callbacks = []
callbacks.append(TensorBoard(log_dir=os.path.join(output_dir,"logs")))

model.fit(
    train_dataset,
    callbacks = callbacks,
    epochs = 3,
)
```

```
Epoch 1/3
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-71-54e2d25b9415> in <module>()
      8     train_dataset,
      9     callbacks = callbacks,
---> 10     epochs = 3,
     11 )

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in autograph_handler(*args, **kwargs)
   1127           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
   1128             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
-> 1129               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
   1130             else:
   1131               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 878, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 867, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 860, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/transformers/modeling_tf_utils.py", line 911, in train_step
        self.optimizer.minimize(loss, self.trainable_variables, tape=tape)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py", line 532, in minimize
        return self.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars, name=name)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/transformers/optimization_tf.py", line 232, in apply_gradients
        return super(AdamWeightDecay, self).apply_gradients(zip(grads, tvars), name=name, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py", line 633, in apply_gradients
        grads_and_vars = optimizer_utils.filter_empty_gradients(grads_and_vars)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/optimizer_v2/utils.py", line 73, in filter_empty_gradients
        raise ValueError(f"No gradients provided for any variable: {variable}. "

    ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: (['tf_camembert_for_token_classification_2/roberta/encoder/layer_._0/attention/self/query/kernel:0', 'tf_camembert_for_token_classification_2/roberta/encoder/layer_._0/attention/self/query/bias:0', 'tf_camembert_for_token_classification_2/roberta/encoder/layer_._0/attention/self/key/kernel:0', 'tf_camembert_for_token_classification_2/roberta/encoder/layer_._0/attention/self/key/bias:0', 'tf_camembert_for_token_classification_2/roberta/encoder/layer_._0/attention/self/value/kernel:0', 'tf_camembert_for_token_classification_2/roberta/encoder/layer_._0/attention/self/value/bias:0', 'tf_camembert_for_token_classification_2/roberta/encoder/layer_._0/attention/output/dense/kernel:0', 'tf_camembert_for_token_classification_2/roberta/encoder/layer_._0/attention/output/dense/bias:0', 'tf_camembert_for_token_classification_2/roberta/encoder/layer_._0/attention/output/LayerNorm/gamma:0', 'tf_camembert_for_token_classification_2/roberta/encoder/layer_._0/attention/output/LayerNorm/beta:0', 'tf_camembert_for_token_classification_2/roberta/encoder/layer_._0/intermediate/dense/kernel:0', 'tf_camembert_for_token_classification_2/roberta/encoder/layer_._0/intermediate/dense/bias:0', 'tf_camembert_for_token_classification_2/roberta/encoder/layer_._0/output/dense/kernel:0', 'tf_camembert_for_token_classification_2/roberta/encoder/layer_._0/output/dense/bias:0', 'tf_camembert_for_token_classification_2/roberta/encoder/layer_._0/output/La...
```

Any clues to solve this gradient issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide some dummy data?

Comment: Sure, I added an example of how does the data looks like and a link to the notebook which I am working on. @AloneTogether

Comment: Here is a like to the dataset: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Odq6eTexLg9ZXCjbWbnZiWMGAqg9Ut45/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Maybe the issue is with the dataset format that I am passing to the model for training. @AloneTogether

Comment: Have you check which metric was officially used for `TFAutoModelForTokenClassification`?

Comment: Didn't find anything official.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try transforming your data into the correct format, before feeding it to `model.fit`:

```py
def map_func(x, y):
  return {'input_ids': x['input_ids'], 'attention_mask': x['attention_mask'], 'labels':y}

train_dataset = train_dataset.map(map_func)
```

The model seems to run after this step.

Comment: I tried this function before and it didn't work, I get a different error now, can you please check the notebook. (TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int')

Comment: I thought that the right format to pass is a tuple in which the 1st part contains the text encodings and the the 2nd contains the label encodings, but that doesn't seem to work because even when I manage to run the training (By defining a loss function), I get a 70% accuracy, but the test fails and the model doesn't accept any batch from the the test dataset, that's why I think it's a data format issue!

Comment: The first issue is coming from `metrics=['accuracy']`, I would remove it.

Comment: Your training is working for me without defining an explicit loss.

Comment: I am training the model normally now, once done I will check for the test data. Is there any other way to check the training accuracy because that issue is kind weird?

Comment: Do you recommend using the internal loss or using a specific one?

Comment: ```model.predict()``` accepts batches now but the test gives wrong results, can you please check them on the notebook.

Comment: @BILLELBENOUDJIT Definitely use the internal loss.

Comment: Any clues for the test issue? @AloneTogether

Comment: it is hard to say what the reason is exactly for "wrong" results.. I do not know your dataset..

Comment: It's weird because it has the same format as the training set, maybe the way I am doing the argmax to get predictions?

Comment: For the accuracy, I tried the ```metric = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy('accuracy')``` but it breaks the training down.

Comment: It's weird, the test doesn't work, the ```model.predict()``` doesn't accept batches anymore.  I opened an new question; https://stackoverflow.com/q/71080976/10701794